# Template Partials in Symfony 2

Tags: templates, symfony, twig, partials

Are there such things as partials in Symfony 2, reusable templates from anywhere, effectively?

I have found `include` http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html but this only allows the rendering of a template in a specific directory structure.

What I really want a folder that contains all my partial templates, rather than lumping them into my main views?

So I want to be able to do something like

```
{% include "Bundle:Default:Partials:view.html.twig" %}
```

**Update**

I do not want to use the enforced structure of `Bundle:Controller:Template` structure. I do not want to use this as it means putting all my template partials in with my main view templates. I need something that lets me do `Bundle:Controller:PartialDir:Template`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can already do that. The symfony2 docs has a section describing how to do this.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#including-other-templates

Comment: This might also be useful (as in the `default('index') ~ '_foo.html'` part): http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#making-an-include-dynamic

Comment: @suihock this isn't what I am looking for. Your solution still enforces the Bundle:Controller:Template structure. I do not want to use this as it means putting all my template partials in with my main view templates. I need something that lets me do Bundle:Controller:PartialDir:Template

Comment: @jakenoble Have you tried Bundle:Controller:Somedir/anotherdir/template.html.twig?

Comment: @jakenoble You can try debugging Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Loader\ FilesystemLoader to see why it isn't finding it. I know that this other format Bundle:Controller/Somedir:template.html.twig works so you could give it a try. It's just that the Controller/Somedir format has a different semantic because this refers to the templates for controllers in the Bundle\Controller\Somedir namespace.

Comment: old - old answer - but the link is eternal!

Answer (score 2):

In Symfony 2.4 (the version I am currently using but it probably works in other 2.x versions as well) you can do the following:

```
{% include '::_partials/partial.html.twig' %}
```

or in Symfony 2.2+ using the include function

```
{{ include('::_partials/partial.html.twig') }}
```

This will look for the partial.html.twig template inside of the app/Resources/views/_partials directory. You can obviously name the _partials directory whatever you want. It also works without the '::' prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but the way to achieve what OP asks is the following:
Rather than doing
`bundle:controler:partialDir:template`
we have to switch it slightly to achieve:
`{% include 'Bundle:PartialDir/Controller:Template' %}`

Answer (score 0):

To include the controller, you'll need to refer to it using the standard string syntax for controllers (i.e. bundle:controller:action):

```
{{ render(controller(
    'App\\Controller\\ArticleController::recentArticles',
    { 'max': 3 }
)) }}
```